# How can I find automatically running scripts on a sever?

Tags: php, cron, scripting

I need to find all the scripts on server which run automatically. The server crashed 2 times yesterday and I need to move all the cron scripts to move to backup server. Please tell me how to identify these scripts ?

Comment: Try reading `/usr/etc/crontab`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming since you mentioned cron that you're on a Linux platform, in which case you can do this,

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do sudo crontab -u $user -l; done
```

This will show the cron jobs for every user on the system, so it will show you which scripts run automatically.

There will probably be some system level ones too, in which case you do this to see them,

```
ls /etc/cron*
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `/etc/cron*` insteadd of just `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: @Michael Mior: At least here, `/etc/crontab` actually runs `/etc/cron.FOO`.

Comment: Same here, except for the case when you need a weird schedule. Like, only run on Fridays in November.

Comment: How can I find all teh cron jobs for all the users?? and where are these jobs stored?

Comment: That's what the first part of my answer does, the "for user in..." command shows you all the cron jobs for all the users. They're stored in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ usually.

Answer (score 3):

crontab -l

and check /etc/crontab

Comment: You should also check `/etc/cron.d` and `/etc/cron.{daily,hourly,weekly}` if they exist. Also, `/etc/anacrontab`.

Comment: How can I find all teh cron jobs for all the users?? and where are these jobs stored?

Answer (score 2):

crontab -l

will list all the scheduled scripts.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will only list cron jobs for the currently logged in user.

Comment: How can I find all the cron jobs for all the users?? and where are these jobs stored?

Answer (score 1):

Take a peek into /var/spool/cron.